# Picard-Lindelöf: "differentiable" instead of "Lipschitz"

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The Picard–Lindelöf theorem states: if $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open neighbourhood of $(0,0)$, and $f\colon U\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in the second parameter (in fact, locally Lipschitz in the second parameter at $(0,0)$ suffices), then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that there is a unique differentiable function $y\colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $y'(t) = f(t, y(t))$ for all $|t|<\varepsilon$, and $y(0)=0$.

It is well known that the condition of Lipschitz continuity cannot be dropped, with a counterexample given by the ODE $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(t,y) = 2\sqrt{|y|}$, which has two different solutions on $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ given by $y_1(t) = 0$ and $y_2(t) = t^2$ for $t >0$ and $y_2(t) = 0$ for $t\leq 0$.

But what if one instead replaces the condition of Lipschitz continuity by asking for $f$ to be *differentiable* in the second parameter? Note that differentiability does not imply local Lipschitz continuity (although *continuous* differentiability does), nor is it implied by it. So this is would be a different version of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, neither stronger nor weaker. But is it true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this isn't working. A procedure similar to the one from my answer to this similar [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455821/existence-and-uniqueness-of-solutions-for-continuous-and-directionally-different/455926#455926) again produces a counterexample.

If $f(t,t^2)=2t$, $f(t,0)=0$, then we have the two solutions $x=0$, $x=t^2$. We now need to extend continuously and make the function differentiable on vertical lines. To do this, fix a smooth $\varphi : [0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $\varphi(s)=0$ near $s=0$, $\varphi(s)=1$ near $s=1$, and let $f(t,x)=2t\varphi(x/t^2)$ for $0\le x\le t^2$.
Finally, we can set $f=0$ below the $t$ axis and $f(t,x)=2t$ above the parabola.

We can also observe (as a consistency check) that $f_x$ gets large near $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks, very smooth!

Comment: @LukasLewark: Thank you! Excuse the silly pun, but it occurred to me later that in fact $f$ is smooth except at $(0,0)$.